# I can't able to SSH into remote server from Jenkins node using public and private Key

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to remote ssh into remote linux machine from Jenkins node. I created public and private key in Jenkins node and copied the public key to authorized_keys in remote machine. But I can't able to remote into remote machine. Please check the logs below.

```
/home/us-jenkins/jenkins/workspace/engineering/dex/college-dex@tmp/durable-9222db0d/script.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
+ ssh -vvv ****@208.53.147.236
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 62: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22 208.53.147.236
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1990977432
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please let me know if any details are needed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` This line means that the connection to the SSH server closed immediately after being opened. the "Executing proxy command" line indicates you're trying to proxy the connection through another ssh connection to 208.53.147.236. The problem could be that the connection to 208.53.147.236 is failing. Make sure that's working before trying to proxy connections through it.

Comment: @Kenster can you please explain in detail if I need to check any file in Jenkins node or in remote server.

Comment: @Kenster I did not find any ssh_config file in ~/.ssh folder. From where this proxy command is getting executed.

Comment: Try commenting the line in ssh_config `#ProxyCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p %p %h`

Comment: @Kenster I can't able to find the ssh_config please find the below details I found in /usr/bin -rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     774568 Jun 26  2019 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     360920 Jun 26  2019 ssh-add-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      10469 Jun 26  2019 ssh-copy-id
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     419208 Jun 26  2019 ssh-keygen
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     441024 Jun 26  2019 ssh-keyscan
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      23920 Oct  9  2019 sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      28000 Oct  9  2019 sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy

Comment: @Kenster please find the files in /usr/bin 
`-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     774568 Jun 26  2019 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     360920 Jun 26  2019 ssh-add
---x--s--x.   1 root nobody   382216 Jun 26  2019 ssh-agent
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      10469 Jun 26  2019 ssh-copy-id
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     419208 Jun 26  2019 ssh-keygen
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     441024 Jun 26  2019 ssh-keyscan
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      23920 Oct  9  2019 sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      28000 Oct  9  2019 sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy
`

Comment: Hi @Kenster I found that  below values in ssh_config.

'GlobalKnownHostsFile /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p %p %hHost *
GSSAPIAuthentication yes

Comment: @Kenster this the same ssh_config which is working for other Jenkins node to SSH into remote server. But for my Jenkins node I can't able to SSH to remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be closed. The issue is our jenkins server is in restricted network hence SSH won't work. We removed the restriction on firewall and the issue was fixed.

Comment: @VonC thanks for your suggestions to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following [SSH Credentials Management with Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222838288-SSH-Credentials-Management-with-Jenkins), make sure you have:

- registered the private key as an SSH credentials in jenkins
- use a passphrase-less private key, or use the [SSH Agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/)
- use both of those elements in your pipeline step

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881959/6309):

```sh
stage ('Deploy') {
    steps{
        sshagent(credentials : ['use-the-id-from-credential-generated-by-jenkins']) {
```

As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019923/i-cant-able-to-ssh-into-remote-server-from-jenkins-node-using-public-and-privat?noredirect=1#comment113222882_64019923), [Jenkins uses a proxy command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36081742/6309) which means its execution user must have a `ssh.config` (like `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) which instructs any SSH call to go through that proxy.

If said proxy fails, that would explain the error message.

Comment: Hi @VonC I registered the private key as an Ssh credential in Jenkins and used sshagent(credentials : ['use-the-id-from-credential-generated-by-jenkins']) in Jenkins Pipeline stage. But still I am receiving the same error.

Comment: @RaghuRam Is your private key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: Inorder to make sure the keys are working fine I copied the Private Key to my Mac machine and tried to SSH into remote server which worked successfully. But when doing SSH from Jenkins I am getting this error.

Comment: Hi @VonC my private key is not protected by passphrase.

Comment: @RaghuRam "Executing proxy command": I did not see at first that part. That would explain the difference between a user session and the Jenkins session.

Comment: @RaghuRam Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/36081742/6309: that could help troubleshoot the proxy step I mention in my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @VonC. I mean to say I replaced my local Mac Laptop private key with Jenkins node Private Key and can able to SSH into remote machine. But if I tried to SSH from Jenkins node it is not working.

Comment: @RaghuRam Yes, because from Jenkins, contrary, I suspect, to your regular user session, it uses a proxy.

Comment: Hi @VonC I checked the .ssh folder and found that it consists of id_rsa
and id_rsa.pub but not ssh.config file. Can you please let me know where to find this ssh.config in Jenkins node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221941/discussion-between-vonc-and-raghu-ram).

Comment: please find the ssh_config details below.
'GlobalKnownHostsFile /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p %p %h

Host *
 GSSAPIAuthentication yes
'

Comment: I added the same but still can't Able to SSH.

Please find the details below for Server where SSH is working fine.
`
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1990977855
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 207.52.152.237:22 as 'administrator'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
`